# Probability of two random variables using Fubini's Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Assume $C$ is a continuous distribution function, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are iid random variables. In addition, $C$ is the distribution for both random variables ($C(z) = \mathbb{P} [Z \le z]$).

I want to show that $\mathbb{P}[Z_1 \le Z_2] = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{E}[C(Z_1)] = \frac{1}{2}$.

I approached it by first showing $\int_{\mathbb{R}} C(z) C(dz) = \frac{1}{2}$, but I struggle from there.

Comment: Note that exactly one of $Z_1 < Z_2, Z_1 = Z_2, Z_1 > Z_2$ must always hold, and that since $C$ is continuous, $\Bbb P[Z_1 = Z_2] = 0$. Now, how do $\Bbb P[Z_1 < Z_2]$ and $\Bbb P[Z_2 < Z_1]$ compare?

Comment: There isn't any information on $\mathbb{P}[Z_1 < Z_2]$ or $\mathbb{P}[Z_2 < Z_1]$.

Comment: Sure there is. You know that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent and have the exact same distribution. That is all you need to know to realize how $\Bbb P[Z_1 < Z_2]$ and $\Bbb P[Z_2 < Z_1]$ must compare to each other.